# Using Two Functions For Password Hashing Python

Tags: function, python-3.x, hash

Trying to create a script that simply accepts a list of passwords, then prints them back out in plain text, and hashed with md5. The problem is I am trying to use two functions and cannot get them to work correctly. The passwordlist function should accept the passwordlist as an argument and then loop through each item in the list and print the actual password, a comma, and then the md5 encrypted password. The makemd5 function is simply to create the hash.

```
import hashlib
passwordlist = ["password","123456","12345678","1234","qwerty","12345",
"baseball","football","letmein","monkey","abc123","mustang","michael"]

def makemd5(key_string):

    new_key_string = key_string.encode('utf-8')

    return (hashlib.md5 ( new_key_string ).hexdigest())

def createmd5list(passwordlist):

    for key_string in passwordlist:

    return (key_string, makemd5)


def main():

    hashlist = createmd5list(passwordlist) 

    print(hashlist)

main ()
```

Comment: Unless this is a school project hasing passwords with MD5 is totally insecure and shoulds not be done—ever. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: This is specifically for school, so the hash itself isn't important, learning how to write the script is the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import hashlib
passwordlist = ["password","123456","12345678","1234","qwerty","12345",
"baseball","football","letmein","monkey","abc123","mustang","michael"]

def makemd5(key_string):

    new_key_string = key_string.encode('utf-8')

    return (hashlib.md5 ( new_key_string ).hexdigest())

def createmd5list(passwordlist):

    for passlist in passwordlist:
        hashlist = makemd5(passlist)
        print (passlist,",",hashlist)


def main():

    passlist = createmd5list(passwordlist) 

    print(passlist)


main ()
```